# Dynamically changing the origin of costmap2D

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d-ros, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

For a project I'm working on, we are using only the dwa_local_planner from the navigation stack. We generate and publish our own occupancy grid as a nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid message and give it to costmap2D. However, the origin of the occupancy grid and thus the costmap2D needs to change dynamically as the robot moves. What is a good way to change the origin of the cost map which it seems to be pulling from the costmap2D config file each time? Will the OccupancyGrid message change it automatically since I will be publishing the dynamically changing origin as a part of the map meta data in the message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207009/dynamically-changing-the-origin-of-costmap2d/) by [sonali](https://answers.ros.org/users/22124/sonali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the rolling_window parameter. http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0